# Python using pd.cut() and np.select( ) condition list based on 80 interval conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'ratio' : [0.25,0.20,0.45,0.10],
        'range': ['1-25','26-50','51-75','76-100']})
degree = pd.DataFrame({'degree':[1,2,5,10,15,13,25,24,26,27,35,40,44,50,73, 80]})
```

I need to add a new column, based on the interval conditions listed as the range. For example, if degree =1, falls into the range of 1-25, then the new column should be should be 0.25. if degree = 24, range = 26-50, the new column should be 0.20.

I used the code below to first cut the degree into intervals, and then use the `np.select`.

```
degree_bin = pd.interval_range(start = 1, end = 101, freq = 25, closed = 'left')
degree['bin'] = pd.cut(degree['degree'], bins = degree_bin)
degree['bin'] = degree['bin'].astype('category') # change into 'category' var

choicelist = data['ratio'].tolist()
condlist  = [degree['bin'] == pd.Interval(1,26,closed = 'left'),
             degree['bin'] == pd.Interval(26,51,closed = 'left'),
             degree['bin'] == pd.Interval(51,76,closed = 'left'),
             degree['bin'] == pd.Interval(76,101,closed = 'left'),
            ]
degree['f'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

But I have over 80 intervals, from 1 to 2000 with the frequency of 25 for my entire dataset. How can I write out the condlist more efficiently? I probably need to adjust how i used the `pd.cut`, so that the bin generated degree['bin'] matches the data['range'].

Comment: Use `map`, or pass the `labels` argument to `pd.cut`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use merge_asof

1. separate on the dash
2. change value type to integer
3. make sure columns are sorted
4. use merge_asof

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame ({'ratio' : [0.25,0.20,0.45,0.10],
        'range': ['1-25','26-50','51-75','76-100']})
degree = pd.DataFrame ({'degree':[1,2,5,10,15,13,25,24,26,27,35,40,44,50,73, 80]})

min_max[['degree', 'max']] = data['range'].str.split("-", n=1, expand = True)
data['degree'] = min_max['degree']

data['degree'] = data['degree'].astype(int)
degree['degree'] = degree['degree'].astype(int)
degree = degree.sort_values(by='degree')

pd.merge_asof(degree, data, on="degree", direction="backward")
```

Result:

[image]